# Regular expressions that removes only first "/"

Tags: php, javascript, expression

I'm new to Regular expressions and can't seem to find out how I have to solve this:

I need a regular expressions that "allows" only `numbers`, `letters` and `/`. I wrote this:

`/[^a-zA-Z0-9/]/g`

I think it's possible to strip the first `/` off, but don't know how.

so `#/register/step1` becomes `register/step1`

Who knows how I could get this result?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try stripping `g` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a non-global match, if the pattern is contiguous in the string:

```
var rx=/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/*)+)/;

var s='#/register/step1';

var s1=(s.match(rx) || [])[0];


alert(s1)>>>  returned value: (String) "register/step1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"/register/step1".match(/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9/]*/); // ["register/step1"]
```

\w is Equivalent to [^A-Za-z0-9_], so:

```
"/register/step1".match(/\w[\w/]*/); // ["register/step1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: Don't know why i didn't suggest this first, but if you're simply enforcing the pattern rather than replacing, you could just replace that slash (if it exists) before checking the pattern, using strpos(), substr(), or something similar. If you are using a preg_replace() already, then you should look at the examples on the function docs, they are quite relevant